# QT: Cannot set-up remote valgrind in qt creator

Tags: qt, valgrind

I'm developing application on mac and would like to use Valgrind as memory leak analyzer.

Could not run local installation of Valgrind (3.13.0) and want try
to connect to remote Valgrind (on virtual box ubuntu).

From Qt documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-valgrind-overview.html):

> You can run the Valgrind tools either locally on the development host
>   or remotely on another host. You can use them to analyze both
>   applications for which you set up a project in Qt Creator and
>   applications for which you do not have a project.

But don't see any options in setting where can I do it.

Qt Creator 4.5.2

That's what I have:

[image]

How can I connect to remote valgrind from qt creator?

Answer (score 0):

Your attached screenshot shows `Valgrind` options only. You can fire `Valgrind` from `Analyze` menu where there are 2 possibilities to fire `Valgrind` remotely:

- `Valgrind Memory Analyzer (External Application)`
- `Valgrind Function Profiler (External Application)`.

Note: I have Qt Creator 4.3.1 so that may differ from yours.